# How to build release version myself with rocketchat 5.x.x #30681

Tags: rocket

I want to make my own changes and deploy as production mode
like this https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/releases
I did it with old version by using meteor (meteor build --server https://xxxx --directory /opt/build)
But I don't know how to do this with version 5.x.x or 6.x.x. Anybody help?

build release function